# MS SQL Server: Count value when value is the only result

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to count a value, where a specific value is the only result when grouped.

For example counting fruits that equals 2139 is simple enough, however counting fruits that are ONLY 2139 when grouped is proving problematic.

```
fruit    number
apples   2139
apples   2139
apples   2139
apples   2139
melon    2139
melon    2138
melon    2138
cherry   2139
cherry   2139
grape    2137
grape    2139
```

My current results (just counting 2139)

```
apples   4
melon    1
cherry   2
grape    1
```

My desired outcome

```
apples   1
cherry   1
```

Comment: Try to do Count(Distinct )

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, maybe `HAVING` is an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having you tried using `except` to exclude fruits with numbers other than 2139?

```sql
create table dbo.Fruits (
  fruit varchar(10),
  [number] int,
);

insert dbo.Fruits (fruit, [number])
values
  ('apples', 2139),
  ('apples', 2139),
  ('apples', 2139),
  ('apples', 2139),
  ('melon', 2139),
  ('melon', 2138),
  ('melon', 2138),
  ('cherry', 2139),
  ('cherry', 2139),
  ('grape', 2137),
  ('grape', 2139);

select fruit, count(1) as [Count]
from (
  select fruit from dbo.Fruits where [number] = 2139
  except
  select fruit from dbo.Fruits where [number] != 2139
) filtered (fruit)
group by fruit;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE(fruit,    number) AS
 (

  SELECT 'apples',   2139 UNION ALL
  SELECT'apples',   2139 UNION ALL
  SELECT'apples',   2139 UNION ALL
  SELECT'apples',   2139 UNION ALL
  SELECT'melon',    2139 UNION ALL
  SELECT'melon',   2138 UNION ALL
  SELECT'melon',    2138 UNION ALL
  SELECT'cherry'  , 2139 UNION ALL
  SELECT'cherry' ,  2139 UNION ALL
  SELECT'grape' ,   2137 UNION ALL
  SELECT'grape',    2139
)
SELECT C.FRUIT
FROM CTE AS C
 GROUP BY C.fruit
 HAVING MIN(C.NUMBER)=MAX(C.NUMBER)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select t.fruit, count (distinct t.fruit)
 from t 
 where t.number = 2139
 and not exists (
    select * from t t2 
    where t2.fruit=t.fruit and t2.number !=2139
)
 group by t.fruit
```